# Julia iterator which parses each line in file

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and have hit a rock with something I imagine should be a common scenario:

I would like an iterator which parses a text file one line at a time. So, like `eachline(f)`, except a function `parse` is applied to each line. Call the result `eachline(parse, f)` if you wish (like the version of `open` with an extra function argument): mapping `parse` over `eachline`.

To be more specific: I have a function `poset(s::String)` which turns a string representation of a poset into a poset:

```
function poset(s::String)
    nums = split(s)
    ...
    return transitiveclosure(g)
end
```

Now I'd like to be able to say something like

```
open("posets7.txt") do f
    for p in eachline(poset, f)
        #something
    end
end
```

(and I specifically need this to be an iterator: my files are rather large, so I really want to parse them one line at a time).

Comment: I just learnt that I can do `for p in (poset(x) for x in eachline(f))` which is good enough for what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would (personally) use for [`Iterators.map`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.map) in such a case:

```
open("posets7.txt") do f
    for p in Iterators.map(poset, eachline(f))
        # do something
    end
end
```

But, as the documentation notes (and as you discovered yourself), this is equivalent to using a [generator expression](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Generator-Expressions):

```
open("posets7.txt") do f
    for p in (poset(x) for x in eachline(f))
        # do something
    end
end
```

Comment: Merci François ! The only improvement I've made over your suggestion is to put a `if !occursin(r"^\s*(?:#|$)", x)` into the generator so I can ignore comment lines.